# How to implement the DERR_ENTRY macro in Guru of the week #32?

Tags: c++

In C++ [Guru of the week #32](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/032.htm) (speaking about "legitimate" use of preprocessor macros), the last example shows a macro called `DERR_ENTRY` without any actual implementation :

> The implementations of DERR_ENTRY and related macros is left to the reader.

This macro is supposed to replace this :

```
 // For outsiders:
enum Errors {
  ERR_OK = 0,           // No error
  ERR_INVALID_PARAM = 1 // <description>
  ...
}

// For the module's internal use:
map<Error,const char*> lookup;
lookup.insert( make_pair( Error(0), "No error" ) );
lookup.insert( make_pair( Error(1), "<description>" ) );
```

with this : (much simpler)

```
DERR_ENTRY( ERR_OK,            0, "No error" ),
DERR_ENTRY( ERR_INVALID_PARAM, 1, "<description>" ),
//...
```

according to the author of GotW :

> We'd like to have both representations without defining the actual information (code/msg pairs) twice. With macro magic, we can simply write a list of errors as follows, creating the appropriate structure at compile time

But I can't see an easy way to define both an enum entry and a map entry at the same time. Or maybe there is unknown syntax I don't know that can solve this ?

So, how would you implement the DERR_ENTRY macro ?

Note : remember that GotW #32 is supposed to illustrate the power of preprocessor macros.

Comment: Do anyone has the book "More exceptional C++". It's said on GotW#32 page that "The solutions in the book have been revised and expanded since their initial appearance in GotW. The book versions also incorporate corrections...". So maybe the answer is in the book ?

Comment: OK after reading the current answers and speaking with some colleagues, we all agree that we can replace the enum with any other type as long as we have type safety and ability to do switch...cases. A solution is still welcome !

Answer (score 3):

What the author may be referring to is the ability to make a macro have different meanings in different places. In this case, you could do the following:

**InternalErrorDefinitions.h**    (This file should not have include guards).

```
DERR_ENTRY( ERR_OK,            0, "No error" )
DERR_ENTRY( ERR_INVALID_PARAM, 1, "<description>" )
...
```

**Errors.h**  (This is the file that will be included by an outside user of the module)

```
#define DERR_ENTRY(err, val, desc) err=val,
enum Errors {
#include "InternalErrorDefinitions.h"
};
#undef DERR_ENTRY
```

**ModuleFile.cpp** (One of the module's implementation files)

```
#define DERR_ENTRY(err, val, desc)  lookup.insert( make_pair( Error(val), desc ) );
map<Error,const char*> lookup;
#include "InternalErrorDefinitions.h"
#undef DERR_ENTRY
```

This allows you to have the error definitions in only one place, while giving them different roles in different places where they are used.

This practice is called [X-Macros](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#X-Macros). See also [this Dr. Dobb's article](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387) explaining them.

Comment: Interesting... Doesn't look like the example in GotW32, but still interesting.

Comment: @Offirmo: Why do you say it doesn't look like the example in GotW32?

Comment: GotW says "replace this (code without macros given above) with that (code with DERR_ENTRY given above)". Your version has a quite complicated replacement code with #define and #include. Of course, we may interpret what is said (replace...) in GotW32...

Comment: @Offirmo: I don't follow your logic. If GotW asks for replacement code, and my code is replacement code, what's the problem? My code does exactly what GotW asks, and is a [known practice](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#X-Macros). If you require that the enum is created like in the original code, you won't find a better solution. Yes, It's a bit complicated, but if it was simple then it would be given in the GotW article instead of being left to the reader.

Comment: I'm sorry... I know that your code is perfectly legit, but just read again GotW : "With macro magic, we can simply write a list of errors *as follows*, creating the appropriate structure at compile time...". What follow are a few macros, not #defines and #includes. I really think (but it's my intuition) that Herb had another solution in mind.

Comment: @Offirmo: I'd like to see how you write macros without `#define`s then.

Comment: It's quite rare to need #define in order to *call* the macros.

Comment: @Offirmo: But it's quite common to need #define to *implement* the macros, which is exactly what's needed here. I feel like you misunderstand either the GotW column or my answer, but I don't know which.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define DERR_ENTRY(name, value, desc) \
    Error::DefineValue name(desc, value);
```

The implementation of `Error::DefineValue` is left to the reader.

Comment: @Offirmo Okay, one more hint. `typedef EnumType<struct Error_tag> Error;`

Comment: How is it possible to dynamically insert new values in an enum ??? That's the thing I never heard of.

Comment: You don't have to. You just make a class whose instances act like an enum's values. (See what it does with `name` in the macro?)

Comment: Ah.. yes of course, if we drop the constraint to have an enum representation, it becomes easy. But then isn't it escaping the problem given in GW 32 ?

Comment: The whole point is to replace the awful code with something better.

Comment: But then why using a macro ? We could call directly your `Error::DefineValue` line without any wrapper macro. I think (but that's my intuition) that the solution "left to the reader" is supposed to illustrate some powerful aspect of macros. Just my thoughts.